# Data Type error while executing a function using dynamic SQL in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jasper-reports, dynamic-sql

I have written a PostgreSQL function which is being called from Jasper iReport for dashboards. When I try and execute the same function manually in pgAdmin I get an error for invalid syntax for type numeric. Please find my Function which is mentioned below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION revenue_dm.trendQuery( IN monthin integer, IN yearin integer  )
  RETURNS TABLE(month1 numeric,year1 numeric,month2 numeric,year2 numeric,month3   numeric,year3 numeric ) AS
$BODY$
       DECLARE

        BEGIN

           month1='select extract (month from (select concat(monthin,''-'',15,''-'',yearin)::date)-30)::numeric';
           month2='select extract (month from (select concat(monthin,''-'',15,''-'',yearin)::date)-60)::numeric';
           month3='select extract (month from (select concat(monthin,''-'',15,''-'',yearin)::date)-90)::numeric';
           year1= 'select extract (year from (select concat(monthin,''-'',15,''-'',yearin)::date)-30)::numeric';
           year2= 'select extract (year from (select concat(monthin,''-'',15,''-'',yearin)::date)-60)::numeric';
           year3= 'select extract (year from (select concat(monthin,''-'',15,''-'',yearin)::date)-90)::numeric';

          RETURN QUERY EXECUTE month1;
          RETURN QUERY EXECUTE month2;
          RETURN QUERY EXECUTE month3;
          RETURN QUERY EXECUTE year1;
          RETURN QUERY EXECUTE year2;
          RETURN QUERY EXECUTE year3;
    END;
    $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

I am using the following query to execute my function in pgAdmin.

```
 SELECT revenue_dm.trendQuery(04,2014);
```

After executing the function, this is the error that I am getting:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "select extract (month from (select concat(monthin,'-',15,'-',yearin)::date)-30)::numeric"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function revenue_dm.trendquery(integer,integer) line 6 at assignment
```

I am not able to debug where in my code am I going wrong in using the dynamic SQL in this function.

Can anyone please help me out in finding out where am I going wrong in this particular function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot use outer variables in dynamic sql. Use `format()` or some similar escape mechanism; or use the `USING` clause for `EXECUTE` (preferred)
2. `RETURNS TABLE(month1 numeric ...` is equal to define an `OUT` parameter, which is `month1 numeric`. In that point of view, you cannot assign a query string to that variable, Postgres will fail trying to parse it as numeric.

Just run a single

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT <multiple fields> ...' USING monthin, yearin;
```

**Edit**: just realized, you shouldn't do a dynamic query at all (there no need for them here)

Just run a single

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT <multiple fields> ...;
```

Comment: How can I assign the result of my single statement `RETURN QUERY SELECT <multiple fields> ...;` to my OUT variable?

Comment: No need to assign anything. `RETURN QUERY` already *returns* the values its selected.

Comment: In My case I have to get three months in three different parameters... So what you are saying, is that if i give `RETURN QUERY select extract (month from (select concat(monthin,'-',15,'-',yearin)::date)-30)::numeric;` then it will return it to the first parameter... and so on respectively??? Is it like that?

Comment: No. Return all column in one query. Like `RETURN QUERY SELECT 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`